# Proxy information without username and password

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I am installing Debian and have been prompted to enter proxy information in standard form of "http://[[user][:pass]@]host[:port]/".
I don't need any username and password to connect through my proxy. What will I enter? Should I include quotes? Should I include all the" [" and "]"  brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to enter square brackets and you don't need to provide the parts in brackets either. It is a standard way in manuals to indicate optional parts of the string, in line with [CLI syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_description_syntax).

Unless you were setting some variable in configuration file, you don't need to enter quotes around URL either.

If your proxy does not need username or password `http://host` or `http://host:port` would be sufficient.